# Does GitHub support environmental secrets into environmental variables?

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to have some environmental variables (which my application/code references) set by "Environmental Secrets" (compare to "Repository Secrets")

For example, I have two Environments setup:

[image]

and as you can see, there's 2x secrets for the `development` environment (note: I've not generated the production secrets, yet. which is why that's empty)

So at first I thought this might work:

```
name: Pull Requests

on:
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'ReadMe.md'

env:
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: true
  MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.my_environmental_var }}

jobs:
 ... etc ...
```

but I was wondering ... how would the GH action 'know' which environment to grab that from?

so is the only way to do this, is to define the env-var on the "job" or "step" level? Like this (on the job level):

```
... snip ...

jobs:

  build_then_test_with_codecov:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment: development
    env:
      MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.my_environmental_var }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

... snip ...
```

Notice how the job defines:

- environment
- env var

Is this the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment)

> Secrets stored in an environment are only available to workflow jobs that reference the environment.

Which means that:

1. In your first example: as you used the secret at the **workflow level**, and **there is no environment informed**, the workflow will get the secret from the repository secrets (not from the environment).
2. In your second example: as you used the secret in the **workflow job**, and you informed the environment `development`, the workflow will get the secret from the environment secrets (not from the repository secrets).

**Full example:**

```yaml
on:
  [...]

env:
  MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.my_environmental_var }} # get secret from the repository secrets

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment: development
    env:
      MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ secrets.my_environmental_var }} # get secret from the development environment secrets
    steps:
        [...]
```

Note that if the environment requires approval, a job cannot access environment secrets until one of the required reviewers approves it.

---

So, answering your question:

**Is the only way to do this, is to define the env-var on the "job" or "step" level?**

Yes, you need to set the env variable at a level where the secret is obtained from the environment, which can only be achieved at the workflow job level or below.